# Python2 PyQt4 Connect a bool Variable to a QCheckBox item

Tags: python, model-view-controller, pyqt, model-view, qcheckbox

I have a problem with QCheckBox.

I am trying to connect a boolean variable to a QCheckBox so that **when I change the boolean variable, the QCheckBox will be automatically checked or unchecked.**

My Question is similar to the Question below but in opposite way.

[question: Python3 PyQt4 Creating a simple QCheckBox and changing a Boolean variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12736825/python3-pyqt4-creating-a-simple-qcheckbox-and-changing-a-boolean-variable)

I just copy one solution from that question to here.

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class SelectionWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.ILCheck = False

        ILCheckbox = QCheckBox(self)
        ILCheckbox.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)

        ILCheckbox.stateChanged.connect(self.ILCheckbox_changed)

        MainLayout = QGridLayout()
        MainLayout.addWidget(ILCheckbox, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.setLayout(MainLayout)

    def ILCheckbox_changed(self, state):
        self.ILCheck = (state == Qt.Checked)

        print(self.ILCheck)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  window = SelectionWindow()

  window.show()
  window.ILCheck = True
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In this case, once I set ILCheck to True, QCheckBox will be checked.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Thanks!!!!

---

Update:

I am using MVC on my project, the code above just a example show what I need. The bool value `ILCheck` will be use in other place, and I don't want call `ILCheckBox` in my model.

I expect that if I modify the value of `ILCheck`, `ILCheckBox` will react correctlly.

---

Update:

Thanks for all your reply and help. All your solution is great!!! The way I need is more like a **Modeling-View** solution so that I can separate modeling part from gui part. When I want to update something, I just need update modeling, and don't need pay attention to what gui looks like. I can't set this Bool property in View Class so that I can't use this solution.

I am not sure MVC is suitable in PyQT. I have a close solution like below with a problem.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, uic
import sys
class CellList(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, cells = [], parent = None):
        QtGui.QStandardItemModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.__cells = cells
        self.add(cells)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QtCore.QString("Cell id List")
    def flags(self, index):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

    def add(self, cells):
        for i in xrange(0, len(cells)):
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem('Cell %s' % cells[i][0])
            if (cells[i][1]):
                item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
            else:
                item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)

            item.setCheckable(True)
            self.appendRow(item)
    def update(self, cells = None):
        # TODO: Making this working with out clean all old Cell
        self.clear()
        if cells is None: 
            cells = self.__cells
        else:
            print "hi"
            self.__cells = cells
        print cells
        self.add(cells)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    listView = QtGui.QListView()
    listView.show()

    data = [[85, True], (105, True), (123, False)]
    model = CellList(data)
    listView.setModel(model)

    data[0][1] = False
    model.update(data)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

There is a problem comes with this solution and I can't solve. I think only a view can set a Model. I am not sure if I can set a model to a single `QCheckBox`.
.

Comment: You can do that with `@property` but I don't see why you would need that. Just expose the checkbox and use `setChecked` instead of assigning to a variable.

Comment: @Avaris Thanks for your help. I am using MVC, so I don't want expose `checkBox` to Model

Comment: I'll write up an answer, but I still think this not the right way. However, I can't suggest anything else (maybe `QDataWidgetMapper`) without understanding your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Avaris shows in his/her answer, emulating the overload of operator `=` is a good start for solving the question. But yet still the problem of the code being
added to the `SelectionWindow` class.

But since we are using `Qt`, lets implement a custom `QObject` that represents our "smart" boolean variable which will emit a signal when 
change its value.

```
class SmartBool(QObject):

    valueChanged = pyqtSignal(bool)         # Signal to be emitted when value changes.

    def __init__(self):
        super(SmartBool, self).__init__()   # Call QObject contructor.
        self.__value = False                # False initialized by default.

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.__value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        if self.__value != value:
            self.valueChanged.emit(value)   # If value change emit signal.
            self.__value = value
```

Now your code needs only a couple of changes:

replace the line:

```
self.ILCheck = False
```

by:

```
self.ILCheck = SmartBool()
```

and connect the signal and the slot, add the line to the _ _ init _ _ some where after the line above. **IMPORTANT, you are not bind to make the connection from within the `SelectionWindow` class**

```
self.connect(self.ILCheck, SIGNAL("valueChanged(bool)"), ILCheckbox, SLOT("setChecked(bool)"))
```

for testing the result just add:

```
 window.ILCheck.value = True
```

to your "main" and you will see the checkbox checked next time you run the example.

**The full code example was added to the end for stetical reasons**

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class SmartBool(QObject):

    valueChanged = pyqtSignal(bool)         # Signal to be emitted when value changes.

    def __init__(self, value=False):
        super(SmartBool, self).__init__()   # Call QObject contructor.
        self.__value = value                # False initialized by default.

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self.__value

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value):
        if self.__value != value:
            self.valueChanged.emit(value)   # If value change emit signal.
            self.__value = value


class SelectionWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ILCheck = SmartBool()          # Your steroides bool variable.
        ILCheckbox = QCheckBox(self)
        self.connect(self.ILCheck, SIGNAL("valueChanged(bool)"), ILCheckbox, SLOT("setChecked(bool)"))
        ILCheckbox.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
        ILCheckbox.stateChanged.connect(self.ILCheckbox_changed)
        MainLayout = QGridLayout()
        MainLayout.addWidget(ILCheckbox, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.setLayout(MainLayout)

    def ILCheckbox_changed(self, state):
        self.ILCheck = (state == Qt.Checked)
        print(self.ILCheck)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  window = SelectionWindow()
  window.show()
  window.ILCheck.value = True
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I realize this is an old post.  But just wanted to say thank you.  I found SmartBool to be helpful.  One improvement note, I found it necessary to change the order of the emit signal in the setter.  If you emit the signal prior to setting the value, you are implementing a valueChanging, not a valueChanged.  Setting the value first and then emitting the signal allows testing against the boolean's new value in the slot handler.

Answer (score 1):

[`property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property) is the way to define a variable that does additional work upon assigning/accessing. Below is the code modified for that purpose. It changes `ILCheck` to a property such that it'll also update the checkbox upon assigning. Proper error checking for `.setter` is left out but most probably needed.

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class SelectionWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SelectionWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self._ILCheck = False

        self.ILCheckbox = QCheckBox(self)
        self.ILCheckbox.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)

        self.ILCheckbox.stateChanged.connect(self.ILCheckbox_changed)

        MainLayout = QGridLayout()
        MainLayout.addWidget(self.ILCheckbox, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.setLayout(MainLayout)

    def ILCheckbox_changed(self, state):
        self._ILCheck = (state == Qt.Checked)

        print(self.ILCheck)

    @property
    def ILCheck(self):
        return self._ILCheck

    @ILCheck.setter
    def ILCheck(self, value):
        self._ILCheck = value
        self.ILCheckbox.setChecked(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = SelectionWindow()

    window.show()
    window.ILCheck = True
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and help. Your solution is great!!! The way I need is more like a Modeling-View solution so that I can separate modeling part from gui part. When I want to update something, I just need update modeling, and don't need pay attention to what gui looks like. I can't set this Bool property in View Class so that I can't use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

just use `ILCheckbox.setCheckState(Qt.Checked)` after calling ILCheck.

You don't neet signals here since you can call a slot sirectly.

If you want to do use this feature more than once, you should consider writing a setter which changes the state of `self.ILCheck` and emits a signal.

Edit after your clarification:

- You can use the setter approach, but instead of setting the value of ILCheckbox, you should call `your_properly_named_anddefine_signal.emit()`. For more information about signal definition see e.g. http://www.pythoncentral.io/pysidepyqt-tutorial-creating-your-own-signals-and-slots/.
- You'll have to connect your signal to a slot which will set the checkbox correctly. This connection could be made in the `__init__()` of your controller class.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am sorry I didn't explain clearly. You can check my update above